# How to Reorder y Axis Labels in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I created the below graph, but I want the labels on the y axis to show in logical order : "Less than $20,000", "$20,000 to $34,999", "$35,000 to $49,999", "$50,000 to $74,999", "$75,000 to $99,999", "Over $100,000" as opposed to the way it is ordered on the graph. I used the following code to create the graph:

```
ggplot(dat2) +
    aes(x = trust, y = income, shape = own, color = own) +
    geom_jitter() +
  scale_color_discrete(name= "Home Ownership",
                       labels=c('Other', 'I Own My Home')) +
  scale_shape_discrete(name = "Home Ownership",
                       breaks=c("0", "1"), labels=c('Other', 'I Own My Home'))
```

How can I reorder the labels on the y axis?

I have tried to reorder the factor but that only returned a data of all .

`dat2$income <- factor(x = dat2$income,  levels = c("Less than $20,000", "$20,000 to $34,999",  "$35,000 to $49,999", "$50,000 to $74,999",  "$75,000 to $99,999", "Over [enter image description here][1]$100,000"))`

I have also tried to use `scale_y_discrete(limits = c("Less than $20,000", "$20,000 to $34,999", "$35,000 to $49,999", "$50,000 to $74,999", "$75,000 to $99,999", "Over $100,000"))` inside the ggplot function but that returned a blank graph with and error message:
"Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
3: Removed 498 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
4: Position guide is perpendicular to the intended axis. Did you mean to specify a different guide `position`?

Comment: You can reorder levels of your variable before ploting `dat2$income <- factor(dat2$income, levels=c("Less than $20,000", "$20,000 to $34,999", "$35,000 to $49,999", "$50,000 to $74,999", "$75,000 to $99,999", "Over $100,000"))`

Comment: that returned the entire variable to NA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reorder the factor before plotting:

```
dat2$income <- factor(x = dat2$income, 
                      levels = c("Less than $20,000", "$20,000 to $34,999", 
                                 "$35,000 to $49,999", "$50,000 to $74,999", 
                                 "$75,000 to $99,999", "Over $100,000"))

ggplot(dat2) +
    aes(x = trust, y = income, shape = own, color = own) +
    ... +
```

# ------------------------- Update ------------------------- #

```
# Without factor reorder
df1 <- data.frame(a = c("Less than $20,000", "$20,000 to $34,999", 
                       "$35,000 to $49,999", "$50,000 to $74,999", 
                       "$75,000 to $99,999", "Over $100,000"),
                 b = 1:6)

ggplot(df1, aes(a, b)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
  theme(axis.text.x.bottom = element_text(angle = 30, vjust = 0.7))
```

[image: Without reorder]

```
# With factor reorder
df2 <- data.frame(a = c("Less than $20,000", "$20,000 to $34,999", 
                       "$35,000 to $49,999", "$50,000 to $74,999", 
                       "$75,000 to $99,999", "Over $100,000"),
                 b = 1:6)
df2$a <- factor(df2$a,
                levels = c("Less than $20,000", "$20,000 to $34,999", 
                           "$35,000 to $49,999", "$50,000 to $74,999", 
                           "$75,000 to $99,999", "Over $100,000"))

ggplot(df2, aes(a, b)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity')+
  theme(axis.text.x.bottom = element_text(angle = 30, vjust = 0.7))
```

[image: With reorder]

Comment: thanks for the answer. but doing only returns missing values. the entire dat2$income becomes NA

Comment: That would undoubtedly work (as shown above). Maybe you had mistype some of the factor characters.